# Looking to render video in game?

Tags: java

I have recently been looking to add a feature which will allow me to render a movie\video into my game. I.e, something pre-rendered and played as the game starts.

I am using Java2D purely so I am curious if there are any frameworks out there that will allow me to do this in an active rendering environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a StackOverflow question asking a similar thing. [Video playback in Java ( JMF, Fobs4JMF, Xuggler, FMJ )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041871/video-playback-in-java-jmf-fobs4jmf-xuggler-fmj)

The answers seem recommend http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler, though its more for encoding/decoding work, or [VLCJ](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj). VLCJ appears to specifically work with AWT and Swing.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6905065) to the question above says it's possible to use VLCJ get BufferedImages - you'll then be able to draw directly with Java2D:

> The other caveat is that the embedded media player won't work with a swing component... you can use the direct media player to get a bufferedimage and display that on whatever you choose, but it will eat into your CPU a bit more (though no more than other players that take this approach.)

**EDIT:** Googling around a bit, I've found this example (from the VLCJ test code infact): [DirectTestPlayer.java](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/direct/DirectTestPlayer.java). This seems to do almost exactly what you need.

Comment: The OP said he was using Java2D, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6905065 suggests a method that can be drawn with Java2d.

Comment: @Thorinll where do you see anything using Java2D in that question?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if its viable without a lot of work. Apparently you can get access to the raw RGB data (see [here](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/2.4.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/direct/RenderCallbackAdapter.html)), but there's still a lot of work to do...

Comment: @Thorinll you should add that to your answer as well, so that the OP doesn't only 25% of an answer.